# Add multiple DateTime Duration strings together using JavaScript to get total duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, duration

I have an HTML Table used to generate a Calendar which shows TimeClock entries for each day a user has worked and clocked in and out of the system.  Each day also shows the total time duration for each clock in/out entry. (multiple "timecard punches" can be within the same day)

Simply put I have DateTime style strings which hold a Duration value and I need to add them all together to get a combined duration value.

In a loop this JavaScript variable `totalTimeValue` will be assigned a duration value as a text string like this `03:31:23`

**Add these duration strings together using JavaScript...**

```
03:31:23
04:21:56
04:08:42
03:31:17
04:10:59
02:48:21
04:26:11
00:00:39
03:41:37
```

---

Using JavaScript and jQuery I have this code below which gets the DateTime Duration value as a string in the format **04:21:19** for each timeclock entry.

My JavaScript/jQuery so far...
Demo of it working here: http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/GpPPPR?editors=101

```
var totalTimeValue = 0;
var totalWeekTimeValue = 0;

// itterate each week which is table row <tr>
$('#timeclock-cal > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
  console.log('=== New Week ===');

  totalWeekTimeValue = 0;

  // get each day which is a table cell <td>
  $(this).find('td').each(function() {
    console.log('== New Day ==');

    // get total time val for each clock in/out on each day which is inside
    // button with CSS class .cal-punch-total-time
    $(this).find('.cal-punch-total-time').each(function() {

      totalTimeValue = $(this).text();

      console.log(totalTimeValue);

      // THIS PART NEEDS YOUR HELP!
      // NEED TO ADD EACH DATETIME STRING TOGETHER FOR TOTAL DURATION VALUES
      totalWeekTimeValue = totalTimeValue+totalWeekTimeValue;

    });

  });

  console.log('= total week time === '+totalWeekTimeValue);
});
```

[full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol53c.png)
[image]

---

I have no objection to using the **MomentJS** library http://momentjs.com/ if it can help in this situation however my research so far did not really show any examples doing what I need to do in this question.

In fact all my StackOverflow and Google searches resulted in no examples of adding durations like this in JavaScript!

I did find this MomentJS plugin **MomentJS Durations** - https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery and Javascript its easily possible. Please have a look at below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pad = function(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2); }
    var totalSeconds = 0;
    $("li").each(function(){
        var currentDuration = $(this).text();
        currentDuration = currentDuration.split(":");
        var hrs = parseInt(currentDuration[0],10);
        var min = parseInt(currentDuration[1],10);
        var sec = parseInt(currentDuration[2],10);
        var currDurationSec = sec + (60*min) + (60*60*hrs); 
        totalSeconds +=currDurationSec;
    });
    

    var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
 totalSeconds %= 3600;
 var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
 var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  $(".totalVal").text(pad(hours)+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(seconds));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>03:31:23</li>
    <li>04:21:56</li>
    <li>04:08:42</li>
    <li>03:31:17</li>
    <li>04:10:59</li>
    <li>02:48:21</li>
    <li>04:26:11</li>
    <li>00:00:39</li>
    <li>03:41:37</li>
</ul>

<div id="totalTime">Total Time:<span class="totalVal"></span></div>
```

Comment: You should add the [radix parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) in the `parseInt()` calls. It's implementation dependent which default value is used (at least until [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2))

Comment: @Andreas - thanks for caching it. I saw the HTML and found that few string values are starting with 0, so radix 8 will be used instead of decimal 10... Thanks...`:)`!

Comment: Awesome thanks it worked out great in my real app http://i.imgur.com/oFEQRz1.png  demo here too http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/GpPPPR?editors=011

Answer (score 1):

This is a little overkill, but shows how to use map and reduce.

```js
/** Calculate the number of seconds from HH:MM:SS **/
function getSeconds(time) {
  var parts = time.split(":");
  return parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 3600 + parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 60 + parseInt(parts[2], 10);
}

//select all the elements
var totalSeconds = $("a.cal-punch-total-time")
    .map( function(ind, elem) { //convert the jQuery object into the array  
        var text = $(elem).text();  //get the text from the anchor
        return getSeconds(text);    //set the index to the total seconds
    })
    .get()  //gets the array out of the jQuery object
    .reduce( function(runningTotal, currentValue){  //Now to combine all the values into one
        return runningTotal + currentValue;  //sum up the values
    },0);  //The initial starting vaule

//Now get the hour, minutes, and seconds from the total seconds
var hours = parseInt( totalSeconds / 3600 );
var minutes = parseInt( totalSeconds / 60 ) % 60;
var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

//left pad numbers less than ten
if(hours<10) hours = "0" + hours;
if(minutes<10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if(seconds<10) seconds = "0" + seconds;


$("#out").html("Total Time: " + (hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="cal-punch-total-time">03:31:23</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">04:21:56</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">04:08:42</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">03:31:17</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">04:10:59</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">02:48:21</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">04:26:11</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">00:00:39</a>
<a class="cal-punch-total-time">03:41:37</a>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function hhmmssToSeconds(str)  {
    var arr = str.split(':').map(Number);
    return (arr[0] * 3600) + (arr[1] * 60) + arr[2];
};

function secondsToHHMMSS(seconds) {
    var hours = parseInt(seconds / 3600, 10),
        minutes = parseInt((seconds / 60) % 60, 10),
        seconds = parseInt(seconds % 3600 % 60, 10);

    return [hours, minutes, seconds].map(function (i) { return i.toString().length === 2 ? i : '0' + i; }).join(':');
}
```

Then:

```
var t1 = hhmmssToSeconds('40:50:40'),
    t2 = hhmmssToSeconds('04:12:30');

var result = secondsToHHMMSS(t1 + t2); // '45:03:10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your DateTime strings into arrays.

```
totalTimeValue = $(this).text().split(':'); //from '03:10:30' to ['03','10','30']
```

Then loop through your array and coerce each string to a number.

```
totalTimeValue.forEach(function(val,idx){
    totalWeekTimeValue[idx] += Number(val);
  });
```

This will leave you with an array of values for totalWeekTime that you can format/recalculate and rejoin if needed.

```
totalWeekTimeValue.join(':'); //[3:10:30]
```

http://codepen.io/hirechrismeyers/pen/ZbVVgr