# How to sum of hours (hh:mm:ss) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time

How to sum of hours (`hh:mm:ss`) in jquery?

For Ex. :
I need to sum of `40:50:40` hours and `04:12:30` hours in jQuery.

And result should be

```
45:03:10
```

Comment: and what is your try ?

Comment: can u provide your code and html

Comment: Time calculations are a solved problem. Use a proper library. http://momentjs.com/ Has duration support.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Oh, more than 500 REP and no [mcve] ?

Comment: Convert to seconds. Sum. Divide with remainder, pad.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705174/add-multiple-datetime-duration-strings-together-using-javascript-to-get-total-du

Comment: this too http://jsfiddle.net/rn56v4dL/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following javascript code...

```
var prodhrd = "40:50:40";
var conprodArr = "04:12:30";
prodhrdArr = prodhrd.split(":");
conprodArr = conprod.split(":");
var hh1 = parseInt(prodhrdArr[0]) + parseInt(conprodArr[0]);
var mm1 = parseInt(prodhrdArr[1]) + parseInt(conprodArr[1]);
var ss1 = parseInt(prodhrdArr[2]) + parseInt(conprodArr[2]);

if (ss1 > 59) {
    var ss2 = ss1 % 60;
    var ssx = ss1 / 60;
    var ss3 = parseInt(ssx);//add into min
    var mm1 = parseInt(mm1) + parseInt(ss3);
    var ss1 = ss2;
}
if (mm1 > 59) {
    var mm2 = mm1 % 60;
    var mmx = mm1 / 60;
    var mm3 = parseInt(mmx);//add into hour
    var hh1 = parseInt(hh1) + parseInt(mm3);
    var mm1 = mm2;
}
var finaladd = hh1 + ':' + mm1 + ':' + ss1;
alert(finaladd);
```

Comment: Yes got the same.. Thanks :)

Comment: why `var mm1 = parseInt(mm1) + parseInt(ss3);` ? can't you write `var mm1 = mm1+ss3;`

Comment: because you need to convert it into `INT`